# Importing key pair using Windows CNG API

Tags: windows, rust, cng

Using the `windows-rs` crate, I'm trying to import an RSA key pair as a `BCRYPT_RSAFULLPRIVATE_BLOB` following these instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-import-and-export

> To import a persisted key:
>
> 1. Create a persisted key by using the NCryptCreatePersistedKey function.
> 2. Set any desired properties on the key object by using the NCryptSetProperty function.
> 3. Set the import key BLOB as a property on the key, with the BLOB type as the property name.
> 4. Finalize the persisted key import by using the NCryptFinalizeKey function.

I'm doing:

```rust
unsafe {
    let mut h = NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE(0);
    NCryptCreatePersistedKey(
        self.handle,
        &mut h,
        to_pcwstr(BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM),
        to_pcwstr(key_name),
        CERT_KEY_SPEC(0),
        if overwrite {
            NCRYPT_OVERWRITE_KEY_FLAG
        } else {
            NCRYPT_FLAGS(0)
        },
    )?;

    let prop_handle = NCRYPT_HANDLE(h.0);

    println!("set export policy");
    let value =
        (NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG | NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG).to_be_bytes();
    let value: *const u8 = addr_of!(value[0]);
    NCryptSetProperty(
        prop_handle,
        to_pcwstr(NCRYPT_EXPORT_POLICY_PROPERTY),
        value,
        std::mem::size_of::<u32>() as u32,
        NCRYPT_PERSIST_FLAG | NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG,
    )?;

    println!("set blob prop");
    NCryptSetProperty(
        prop_handle,
        to_pcwstr(BCRYPT_RSAFULLPRIVATE_BLOB),
        to_import.as_ptr(), // to_import is a Vec<u8>, structured as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_rsakey_blob
        to_import.len() as u32,
        NCRYPT_PERSIST_FLAG | NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG,
    )?;
    println!("finalize key");
    NCryptFinalizeKey(h, NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG)?;
    h
}
```

but I encounter a failure on the first call to `NCryptSetProperty` with `NTE_NOT_SUPPORTED` error code.

The storage used is `StorageProviderType::Tpm` as `StorageProviderType::Soft` doesn't work on my system for some reason (can't open it)

What am I missing? Can't we set `NCRYPT_EXPORT_POLICY_PROPERTY` for a RSA key?

Comment: Is this a "how do I call the API" question?  Then reproduce the problem in C.  Or is it a "In C this works, what's wrong with my Rust translation" question?

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for your answer :) I've reproduce the error in C, when using MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER. It does work in C using MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER. But in Rust, I often encounter code: 0xC0000225 when opening this provider and I can't find any clue on why :-/ It works like once every now and then :-/

Comment: Which provider do you want to use?  If you want Rust code behaving like the working C code (using MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER) then I suggest you add the working C version into your question; that will allow Rust users with experience in DLL calls to help you even if they know nothing about the cryptographic providers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for your answer again! I found out what was wrong with my code (https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-the-compiler-didnt-catch-this-one-pointer-vs-lifetime/76987). But it doesn't explain why I can't set NCRYPT_EXPORT_POLICY_PROPERTY with a MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER (neither in Rust nor C)